How to handle 'handshake error in client' with expired SSL certificate in Flutter?
I am encountering an issue while working on a Flutter project. I am trying to make an HTTP request to a server with the following code:
Future<String> getTargetVersion() async {
    String kioskId = ConfigLoader().getKioskId;
    String apiKey = 'myAPIKEY';
    String versionCheckUrl = 'https://ai.wizservice.co.kr:1002/api/kiosk/$kioskId/config';
    var url = Uri.parse(versionCheckUrl);
    try {
        var response = await http.get(url,
            headers: <String, String>{
                'X-Authorization': apiKey,
            },
        );
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
            var version = jsonResponse['version'];
            return version;
        } else {
            logger.e("Failed to load version");
            throw Exception('Failed to load version');
        }
    } catch(e){
        writeAppLog("An error occurred while fetching the target version: $e");
        throw Exception('Failed to load version');
    }
}

However, I am encountering the following error:
"handshakeexception: handshake error in client (os error: i/flutter (27098): │ ! certificate_verify_failed: certificate has expired(handshake.cc:393))."
I suspect this is due to an expired SSL certificate on the server.
Could anyone suggest how I can handle this issue? I have considered bypassing SSL certificate validation using the badCertificateCallback, but I am encountering difficulties implementing it due to null safety issues. Are there any other approaches or best practices to handle this situation effectively?
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =      
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}

A value of type 'bool Function(X509Certificate, String, int)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool Function(X509Certificate, String, int)?'. (Documentation)  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'bool Function(X509Certificate, String, int)?'.
I encountered an error like this.
I'm sorry for posting this using a translator because my English is not good. There are many answers, but I tried to solve the problem with those answers but failed, so I'm posting the question like this.
Thank you in advance for any insights or suggestions.

The best practice would be to contact the website administrator and have them renew their certificate.

Thank you for your reply. I wanted to try something on my own, but I guess I'll have to contact them first. Thanks again for the reply. Hope you have a nice day.
